# Can't parse JSON Object, Stringify or get javascript property

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm using a firefox addon that provides me with this variable:

```
[{errorMessage:"TypeError: a is null", sourceName:"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/graphics.js", 
lineNumber:17, console:null}]
```

From firebug, I can see this variable and its called "e".

I can type in e, and the print it as it is above.

If I type e.toString(); I get,

[object Object]

If I type e.errorMessage, it is undefined.

If I type JSON.parse(e), I get unexpected character error.

How can I get the information out of this object? It seems that anything I do to it, it just returns either [object Object] or undefined.

I've tried JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, iterating through it, and nothing provides me with the actual object information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not JSON. It is a JavaScript array. It has nothing to do with JSON in any way.

To access a JavaScript array, just use ordinary JavaScript code, not `JSON.parse` or anything like that.

You could use `JSON.stringify()` to turn this array *into* JSON, but that certainly isn't what you want.

The reason `e.toString()` prints `[object Object]` is simply that this is what the `.toString()` method returns for an object or array. `.toString()` does not always give a useful result.

Paste the following into Firebug or the Chrome console and see what it logs:

```
var e = [
    {
        errorMessage: "TypeError: a is null",
        sourceName: "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/graphics.js",
        lineNumber: 17,
        console:null
    }
];

console.log( e.length );
console.log( e[0] );
console.log( e[0].errorMessage );
console.log( e[0].sourceName );
console.log( e[0].lineNumber );
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an array containing an object, try this:

```
e[0].errorMessage;
```

Comment: I tried this, but the return is 'undefined'. I'm doing this in firefox console.

Comment: also note, there should be double quotes around the keys as well, not just the values. So in your JSON *errorMessage* should have double quotes around it to be valid JSON

Comment: Is there a way to modify this after I already have the object?

Comment: Looks like this is proboably a Firefox console bug.. I was able to get it through Chrome.

Comment: @A.O. - This is not JSON, so JSON syntax rules do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

#### From the JSON Specification: [RFC 4627][1]

[2.2. Objects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2)

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).
> **A name is a string.**  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value. A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

[2.5. Strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5)

> A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

---

#### In the official ECMAScript specification:

It defines an [Object Literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), which a PropertyNameAndValue can be a StringLiteral or an IdentifierLiteral.
And an [IdentifierLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), does not have quotes.

Unquoted keys names are legal and allowed in Javascript but they are not valid JSON.

---

http://jsonlint.com

```
[
    {
        errorMessage: "TypeError: a is null",
        sourceName: "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/graphics.js",
        lineNumber: 17,
        console: null
    }
]
```

Results

```
Parse error on line 3:
...a is null",        sourceName: "http://
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

Comment: It's not JSON. It's a JavaScript array.

Comment: @MichaelGeary If it is not JSON it will not parse with a JSON parser. However arrays are allowed in JSON `A JSON text is a serialized object or array.` http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2

Comment: That's right, it isn't JSON, so a JSON parser won't parse it. JSON is a *string* format for serializing JavaScript objects and arrays. But this is a JavaScript array already, not a JSON string. OP saw the output from Firebug - a JavaScript object literal - and mistook it for JSON. That's the only connection with JSON here: a simple mistake. So JSON syntax rules don't apply here at all.